# pgAudit on Windows - How to add #include Source Files

Tags: c, windows, postgresql, visual-studio-code, audit

I see so much info about pgAudit on Linux. I need some guidance on how to build and add the pgAudit extension to postgresql on windows.

I have done the following:

Clone the pgAudit extension:

```
git clone https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit.git
```

Change to pgAudit directory:

```
cd pgaudit
```

Checkout REL_11_STABLE branch (note that the stable branch may not exist for unreleased versions of PostgreSQL):

```
git checkout REL_11_STABLE
```

**This is where it Gets Tricky for me:**

Build pgAudit and run regression tests:

```
make check USE_PGXS=1
```

Install pgAudit:

```
make install USE_PGXS=1
```

I pull the repo and installed MinGw
[image]

I have added the following extensions to vs code: 
[image]

```
    #include "postgres.h"
    #include "access/htup_details.h"
    #include "access/sysattr.h"
    #include "access/xact.h"
    #include "access/relation.h"
    #include "catalog/catalog.h"
    #include "catalog/objectaccess.h"
    #include "catalog/pg_class.h"
    #include "catalog/namespace.h"
    #include "commands/dbcommands.h"
    #include "catalog/pg_proc.h"
    #include "commands/event_trigger.h"
    #include "executor/executor.h"
    #include "executor/spi.h"
    #include "miscadmin.h"
    #include "libpq/auth.h"
    #include "nodes/nodes.h"
    #include "nodes/params.h"
    #include "tcop/utility.h"
    #include "tcop/deparse_utility.h"
    #include "utils/acl.h"
    #include "utils/builtins.h"
    #include "utils/guc.h"
    #include "utils/lsyscache.h"
    #include "utils/memutils.h"
    #include "utils/rel.h"
    #include "utils/syscache.h"
    #include "utils/timestamp.h"
    #include "utils/varlena.h"
```

I am not sure how to add #Include and then build and add to postgres. Are there any better tutorials or screenshots for doing this on windows 10? I am having such a hard time finding simple tutorials to do this.

Comment: Please do not post images of text that you can have just as easily posted into a code block.

Comment: I will remove and add the text. Thank you